# What is a non-wiki question?

Tags: support, stackexchange, community-wiki, profile-page

On [my CR profile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/26940/shankbond), I have seen a number of tags related to questions I have asked.  When I hover over these tags, it says "asked non-wiki questions."  What is it?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a wiki question.  10 edits by the author or edits from 5 different users can turn a question into a wiki question.  Only a ♦ moderator can manually turn a question into a wiki. That helps in more people getting interested in making the question better. If it is community wiki, then nobody receives rep and everyone starts contributing without hesitation of someone getting the rep for all their hard work.

Anything which has a particular user associated with it is non-wiki.

For more information, see the [Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: Another question is: Do wiki questions make sense here?

Comment: @svick Didn't get you.

Comment: Code Review is kind of weird Stack Exchange site. Here, both questions and answers are more personal than elsewhere, so I can't see how would community wiki question or answer be useful for Code Review.

Comment: @svick Not necessarily. There are a lot of standard algorithms. If someone starts to implement them in any particular language and ask for reviews then there is scope for community wikis. Also in case of an actual project with more than one members there is scope of community wiki. There can be lot of such hypothetical scenarios. But I don't see any of them happening anytime soon.

Comment: Also, overall, the CW system is still in place to discourage excessive editing for bumping.  That part, at least, won't go away on this site.

Comment: @svick: In the case of something like example code or even libraries, CW could be more relevant.  Of course, those questions are in the minority here.